# Why is each line of code giving me "invalid context"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

This is my code in which every line is giving me an "invalid context" error when running the app in the iPad Simulator.  Every statement after "self.Frame = frame; gives the error.  How do I fix it?

```
- (void)makeFrame:(CGRect)frame number:(NSInteger) number color:(UIColor *) color {

    float rd1 = 225.00/255.00;
    float gr1 = 102.00/255.00;
    float bl1 = 0.00/255.00;

    float rd2 = 225.00/255.00;
    float gr2 = 153.00/255.00;
    float bl2 = 0.00/255.00;

    self.frame = frame;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd1 green:gr1 blue:bl1 alpha:1.0]; 
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]]; 
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:0.5];  
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:10]; 
    self.tag = number;  //  set each button's tag
    [self setClipsToBounds: YES];

    //  do date label
    date = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 65, 40 )]; 
    date.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //  x  y   w   h
    date.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd2 green:gr2 blue:bl2 alpha:1.0];
    date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
    date.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:40];
    //   date.alpha = 0.2;
    [self addSubview:date];
}
```

And this is the code which calls makeFrame:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    allButtons = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int k = 40, m = 0; m < 6; m++, k+= 42)   //  this controls the vertical distance between rows
        for(int i = 0, j=32; i < 7; i++, j+=102) {  //  this controls the size and horizontal distance
            calendarButton *cb= [calendarButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [cb makeFrame:CGRectMake(j, k, 100, 40) number: allButtons.count+1 color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            //                       x  y   w   h
            [self.view addSubview:cb];
            [allButtons addObject:cb];  // put it in the array
        }

    calendarButton *cb= [calendarButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cb drawRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 40)];   //  150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manually calling `drawRect`, which I suspect is causing this problem. From the docs:

> You should never call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method instead.

This doesn't look necessary in this case, though. The view has been added as a subview of your view; it will automatically draw itself when your view renders.

Comment: Thank you so much!  that was it... duh!  I know it's an override...don't know why I didn't see it...

Comment: I have one related question:  does the "drawRect" get called for every "drawing" in that class?  In other words, do I need a separate class for each drawing that doesn't need that particular override?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "drawing". `drawRect` will be called once for every `UIView` subclass. The default `drawRect` basically just draws its background and then calls `drawRect` for all of its subviews. Any view you have that needs to do something special (like drawing a `CGPath` or something) needs to implement `drawRect`. If you aren't doing custom Core Graphics drawing, you don't need to implement it at all, since UIKit already has most rendering tools built-in (ie, if you're drawing an image, use a `UIImageView`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access view properties in view controller. In your case `self` is UIViewController (or sublcass), change it to `self.view` in order to access to view

E.g.

```
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I think that `makeFrame` is a method in the `calendarButton` class, not the view controller.